# How to disable auto suggestion in Hugging Face vscode extension

Tags: vscode-extensions, huggingface

I'd like to disable the auto suggest/complete of hugging face in vscode.  So if I want a suggestion I would hit the key combination cmd+shift+L.  It'a annoying to always have suggestions come up if I'm just thinking about something and then have to hit escape to make it go away.  Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

setting editor.inlineSuggest.enabled to false fixed it.